# The address of my object in a vector changes

Tags: c++, c++11

I filled a vector with `A` objects, then stored these objects address in a `multimap` [1], but the print message shows that the reference to the object stored in the vector changed [2]. Do you see why? and how avoid any changes.

```
//[1]
vector<A> vec; 
multimap<const A*, const double > mymultimap;

for (const auto &a : A) {
  double val = a.value();
  vec.push_back(a);
  mymultimap.insert(std::pair<const A*, const double >( &vel.back(), val)); 

  // displaying addresses while storing them    
  cout<<"test1: "<<&vec.back()<<endl;

}

//[2]
// displaying addresses after storing them
for(auto &i : vec)
    cout << "test2: " << &i <<endl;
```

Results:

```
test1: 0x7f6a13ab4000  
test1: 0x7f6a140137c8  
test2 :0x7f6a14013000  
test2 :0x7f6a140137c8
```

Comment: Please add correct code.

Comment: `for (const auto &a : A) {` - what is that?

Comment: why do you store adresses? There are references to elements in a vector that are valid always (e.g.  `vec[i]` for the i-th element)

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.

Answer (score 7):

You are calling `vec.push_back(a)` within your `for` loop. Therefore the vector may re-allocate the underlying array if it runs out of space. Therefore the address of the previous elements are no longer valid if they were copied to the new memory location.

For example say you allocated 3 elements and stored their addresses. After pushing back a 4th element the vector has to reallocate. That means the first 3 elements will be copied to a new location, then the 4th will be added after that. Therefore the address you had stored for the first 3 are now invalid.

Comment: Dear CopyKramer, yes this was you problem, thank you for your answer. Regards

Answer (score 4):

Iterators (and references and object adresses) are not guaranteed to be preserved when you call `vector<T>::push_back()`. If the new `size()` is greater than current `capacity()`, a reallocation will happen and all the elements are moved or copied to the new location.

To avoid this, you can call `reserve()` before you start inserting.

Comment: Dear Krzaq, yes you are right and vec.reserve() worked well. Regards

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the `reserve()` method as if someone later calls `push_back()` it may invalidate "the world" of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

One of the main features of `std::vector` is that it stores its elements in **contiguous memory** (which is great for performance when you visit vector's items on modern CPUs).

The downside of that is when the pre-allocated memory for the vector is full and you want to add a new item (e.g. calling `vector::push_back()`), the vector has to allocate another chunk of *contiguous* memory, and copy/move the data from the previous location to the new one. As a consequence of this re-allocation and copy/move, the address of the old items can change.

If for some reason you want to preserve the address of your objects, instead of storing *instances* of those objects inside `std::vector`, you may consider having a vector of *pointers* to objects. In this case, even after the reallocation, the object pointers won't change.

For example, you may use `shared_ptr` for both the `vector`'s items and the `multimap`'s key:

```
vector<shared_ptr<const A>> vec;

multimap<shared_ptr<const A>, const double> mymultimap;
```